# Presenting a XIB View Freezes

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xib, presentviewcontroller

In storyboard I have a button on my Main Menu called showCountdownViewControllerPressed.

This button is supposed to show my XIB called TimerViewController.

But when I run the app, it freezes upon button press and then after a little while crashes the app.

I put this action in my CRViewController.m (my main menu)  [I also have imported the TimerViewController.h in this file]

```
- (IBAction)showCountdownViewControllerPressed:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"showTimerViewController");
    TimerViewController *timeController = [[TimerViewController alloc]
                                  initWithNibName:@"TimerViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self presentViewController:timeController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

[image: CRViewController Countdown Clock Button]
[image: XIB TimerViewController]
[image: Memory]
[image: TimerViewController Make-up]
[image: Breakpoint Exceptions]

Comment: what error you get ?

Comment: thats the weird thing, I don't get any errors.  It just says Xcode quit unexpectedly.  When I run it on my test device, it just freezes, and then crashes.  I get the NSLog Statement however.

Comment: What is the content of `TimeViewController`, it seems the memory usage is too high, the app may crash under that situation.

Comment: @gabbler added image above

Answer (score 0):

That's not the answer to your problem but it can help. I'm putting it here because I can't add images on the comments. You can put an exception breakpoint at the bottom of the breakpoints tab, normally it will stop just before the crash and you will get more info about it.

[image]

Post where the exception breakpoint it's stopping for getting more help :)

Comment: Have you tried to initialize the TimeViewController with [NSBundle mainBundle] instead of nil?

Comment: No, how would that look?

Comment: TimerViewController *timeController = [[TimerViewController alloc]
                                  initWithNibName:@"TimerViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

Comment: Would it mean anything if the view I am presenting is for Landscape view mode only?

Comment: It's possible yes, have you tried to put the view in portrait?

Comment: Well the view won't fit in portrait.

Comment: Yes I guess that, but that's just for knowing if that's the problem :)

Comment: Tried portrait, still got the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if it is LandScape only, you can add this in `TimerViewController` for iOS 8, which will make the `TimerViewController` rotate to the landscape mode.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
}
```